# how to match string with dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

**I have one list as below**

```
listvalue = ["POS 541919XXXXXX5316 WWW PAYTM COM POS DEBIT","POS 541919XXXXXX5316        HASBRO CLOTHING POS DEBIT","Salary for the month of April 2018"]
```

**I have one dataframe as below :**

```
           variable                   value
0          ATM Cash                 withdrawal
8       Auto & Fuel                    fuel
16          Expense                    fees
17          Expense                    goods
18          Expense                 stationery
19          Expense                  purchase
20          Expense                  material
21          Expense                 telephone
24  Food/Restaurent                   food
25  Food/Restaurent                  catering
32          General                  others
40        Groceries                  big bazar
48           Income                   salary
49           Income                 deposit
50           Income                  rewards
56          Medical                    dr
57          Medical                   doctor
58          Medical                    dr.
59          Medical                  nursing
60          Medical                pharmacist
61          Medical                 physician
62          Medical                 hospital
63          Medical                  medicine
64  Mobile recharge                 airtel
72          Payment                 tranfer
73          Payment                payment
80         Shopping                 cloths
81         Shopping               clothing
88           Travel                 travel
```

I have to compare each `listvalue` in value dataframe. If any word of value from dataframe in listvalue, i want to print variable of that value.

Comment: What have you tried and what problems did you run into? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you mean sth like this:

```
words = ' '.join(listvalue).upper().split()
idx = df.value.str.upper().isin(words)

In: df[idx]
Out: 
    variable     value
48    Income    salary
81  Shopping  clothing
```

Comment: If value of dataframe matches with listvalue i want variable of that value

Comment: output should be

Comment: variable               value \n
   Shopping        clothing \n
    Income                salary \n

Comment: `I have to compare each listvalue in value dataframe. If any word of value from dataframe in listvalue, i want to print variable of that value.` That's exactly what I did: check if value from dataframe is in list, print dataframes variable and value. Where does anything with "Income salary" come from - you didn't say anything about this in your question??

Comment: third index in listvalue has salary so i need to print income variable aswell

Comment: Ah, understand. I thought it's only about those uppercase words. Then simply make all words in listvalues uppercase, too. See edit.

Comment: thank you.If there is no match of value in listvalue i want to print general

Comment: first index in listvalue has no match in value so i need to print general in this case

Comment: what does "print general" mean?

Comment: Can we do the same thing without spliting the listvalue?...If it yes can u send me code snippet

Comment: Splitting is the easiest way to go for checking if `df.value` is in `words`. and you still have the unsplit Version stored in `listvalue`, so what is the problem here?

Comment: Some listvalue contains other special characters without space so that time we cant split using space.For this reason without splitting i have to do.

Comment: Too vague, either you know how the words in your list are separated, then please tell and then there will be a way to split them. Otherwise you don't know, then neither you, nor me, nor anybody else can write a program which does this job for you simply because you don't give the requirements what the program shall do.